# Understanding the Difference Between Independent and Dependent Variables

Tags: correlation, causality, predictor, scatterplot, dependent-variable

I'm new to statistics and I'm struggling to grasp the distinction between an independent and a dependent variable. For instance, if I want to examine the correlation between daily COVID-related deaths and the number of Facebook posts made on the same day, I believe that the number of daily deaths should be my independent variable (plotted on the x-axis of my scatter plot). I want to determine whether the number of deaths influences the number of posts. However, I've been informed that my thinking is incorrect, and I'm having trouble understanding why. Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You *can* say that *daily COVID-related deaths* is your independent variable and *the number of Facebook posts* (on COVID?) your dependent variable (some would prefer other terms, but these are quite common in some fields). It does not make much sense the other way. *But* I guess that the criticism comes not for the use of terms, but the interpretation. This is just a correlation; for some people *influence* might sound a strong, causal verb.

Comment: Welcome to the site Diana, this analysis makes perfect sense to me: I've run similar ones (mine were about vaccine uptake effect on social media). If you are conceptualizing this as the influence of deaths on posts, then deaths is indeed independent and posts dependent. [ Unsolicited advice: As @T.E.G. intimated, statisticians have conniptions when anyone uses causal language (i.e. "influences"), but since you have data in time we can develop more convincing evidence of causality than usual by seeing if the number of deaths leads the number of posts (check out "cross correlation"). ]

Comment: Typically the "dependent" variable is thought to depend on the others, that is, it is the target of your prediction ("target variable" is also used). Note that in a regression you can choose whatever you want as dependent or independent variable, which is why additional knowledge is needed to get causal insights from a statistical model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Variable Definitions

The wording conveys, with caution, the nature of each variable.

The **dependent variable** is the variable being acted upon. It is *dependent* on the influence of other factors. Generally speaking, you can sometimes refer to this as the **outcome** or **response**, which conveys that it is the result of some other influence. In other words, if $x\rightarrow{y}$, then $y$ is our outcome.

The **independent variable** is the force acting upon the dependent variable. It is assumed that other forces are not acting upon it, hence it is "independent." This of course isn't entirely true, we simply model it this way for simplicity if we do not have a theoretical purpose for modeling it as influenced by other factors.

Which of your variables is used in this case largely depends on what you think is theoretically valid, as you could technically model both as independent variables and dependent variables. Do deaths "cause" Facebook posts? Do Facebook posts "cause" more deaths? It's probably unlikely that Facebook causes deaths (at least not in the way implied here), so your more likely candidates here would be:

$$
\text{IV} = \text{COVID deaths}
\\
\text{DV} = \text{Facebook posts}
$$

##### Correlation and Causation

Keep in mind the old adage that "correlation does not imply causation" and that a correlation simply measures the covariance of two variables. For a Pearson correlation, that means:

$$
r = \frac{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\Sigma(x_i-\bar{x})^2 \Sigma(y_i-\bar{y})^2}}
$$

Which can be alternatively represented as:

$$
r = \frac{Cov(x,y)}{{S_x}{S_y}}
$$

Both equations dictate that the covariance of the variables is divided by their standard deviations. In essence, this means we can only say that each variable is associated with each other, but we don't know which causes which. Returning to one of your points:

> I want to determine whether the number of deaths influences the number
> of posts.

We can only say they are *associated*, we cannot directly infer that our IV of COVID deaths indeed influences or causes Facebook posts. Consider for example these two scatterplots, which simply have their axes reversed:

[image]

Does flower petal length cause petal width? Or vice versa?. With that in mind, be careful with your wording when conducting a correlation. How you word your explanation matters, and only more sophisticated statistical analysis can attempt to answer more causal questions.

Comment: I suppose if the OP is assessing social media posts *referring to* daily deaths then the necessary causal ordering is more or less established.

Comment: I think it would greatly depend on how time is treated. If they are obtaining a correlation of, say, daily deaths and daily posts, this could be heavily influenced by lagged effects and other influences. If we were to take, say, Time 1 Deaths and Time 2 Posts, then we could at least move closer to causality.